What is the significance of Paramus as the location of Ralph Bohner's one-man show in "Agatha All Along"?
In the Agatha All Along episode "Familiar by Thy Side" (S01E06), Billy Kaplan encounters Ralph Bohner, who was also known as "Pietro Maximoff" in WandaVision (played by Evan Peters). The episode reveals that Ralph has been left psychologically scarred and paranoid of witches following the events in Westview.
When Ralph shares his experiences with Billy, he makes an unusual offer:

So, I accept cash or… I can give you half-off tickets to my one-man show in Paramus. I really need to fill seats.

This line seems intended to humorously illustrate Ralph's desperation. However, I'm curious about the specific choice of Paramus as the location for his show. What makes Paramus a particularly funny or odd location as opposed to other locations?

Paramus is a small town in New Jersey with population of c.25,000. It's not a hot-bed of entertainment options although it is a major shopping destination.
It's something of a trope that unsuccessful artists will be reduced to putting on shows in the Paramus Mall in order to get any sort of audience.
